# How to build chromium's cronet library for Linux desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, network-programming, chromium, cronet

I would like to use chromium's [network stack](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/components/cronet?autodive=0%2F%2F) for desktop applications, from what I heard it was developed for mobile platforms. Is there a way to build it for desktop platforms?

Answer (score 1):

I built the cronet on Linux about a year ago. First install `deps_tools` according to [this link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md) and then build the cronet according to it's [build instruction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/components/cronet/build_instructions.md).

Comment: Hi, yes you can build on windows or linux, that's the "build machine" which is different of the deployment machine, where the library will be used. By default it can be deployed only on Android, iOS, Chrome OS and Fuchsia.

Comment: Have you tried this recently? I'd like to use this and curious if it's still viable.